# What "phone call" is Neo referring to?

Tags: the-matrix

In *Matrix* (1999), Agent interrogates Neo about Morpheus:

> Neo: That sounds like a really good deal. But I got a better one.
> How about...I give you the finger....and you give me **my phone call**.

What "phone call" is Neo referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a U.S.-specific reference to the [Sixth Amendment's](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/sixth_amendment) [Right to Counsel](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/right_to_counsel).  (The "sixth amendment" is an amendment to the [U.S. Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_States).)  It is frequently represented as "a right to a phone call," with the intention being that the person arrested (or accused) by police will call a lawyer.  (Or call someone to find a lawyer for them.)

Note that this is part of the judicial basis for the [Miranda warning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_warning) that is frequently portrayed in U.S. movies and T.V. shows.